# Javascript Code explanation. Image sequence

Tags: javascript, html, image

I was wondering if you guys would be able to tell me what these last 2 lines mean in some code which will change images according to where they are in the sequence. It will change whenever I hit a button

```
var image = document.getElementById('light');
image.src=list[light];
```

Hope you are able to help me.
Thanks
PS: That code is found near to the end of my whole code

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp. He/she is setting the image according to a given index(light) of an array(list).

Comment: Could you explain what you just said in simpleton terms? I am a little confused. Is what you said what both code will achieve?

Comment: look at @Telman answer. `list[light]` is an URL. `list` is an array and `light` is the index of that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var image = document.getElementById('light');
```

This line sets the variable `image` to an element in the page with the id 'light'.

```
image.src=list[light];
```

This sets the src of the image to the value of list[light].

If list is an array then `light` will be a number to refer to the element of the array.

Alternatively if `list` is an object `light` could be a string.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can I ask you 1 more question related to this?

Answer (score 0):

That code gets an element by it's ID value and updates the source of the image, presumably to a different image.

Answer (score 0):

Here you just get a reference to the image object.

```
var image = document.getElementById('light');
```

On the second line you change `src` property of image object to some different value, what is automatically triggers the reloading of image.

```
 image.src=list[light];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can I ask you 1 more question related to this?

Comment: Are you able to tell me what this section of the code does?  (image === list.length) image = 0